# Abstract class giving error while creating object of derived class

Tags: c++, abstract-class

```
class base
{
    public:
    virtual void display() = 0;
};

class derived : public base
{
    void display()
    {
        //print display of derived//some code
    }
};

int main() {
    derived d;
}
```

When I run the above code, it gives an error that I can't create an object of abstract class; however, my derived class is not a abstract class.

Can anyone explain why there is an error?

Comment: This is a simple typo. Remove the extra `{` in the derived class to fix this problem. [Demo](http://ideone.com/ZW2gYt)

Comment: That code is correct and should compile. The error is somewhere else. As a simple advice, when asking about a compiler error, it is quite helpful to provide the exact error in the question, as the compiler is most probably providing insight into what it thinks is wrong.

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/28KTRR). Can you provide more info?

Comment: What David says; most compilers say something like "class is abstract because of pure virtual function xy" on further lines of errors like this. For example, make sure that the function name is not misspelled in one of the classes.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra {.  public base { {